# Automated Testing (Watir): Retrieving data and implementing into your test?

Tags: copy, watir, rubymine, reusability

I am just getting started with automated testing on RubyMine using Watir webdriver. So far I am having a blast and I find it works really well, even for a newb like me! :)

I want to create a test which retrieves an order code that is generated during the test and then later use the same code to run an 'include?' verification query on a different page.

I know I can use an HTML selector to show Watir where the code is, I want to know how to copy it and use it later. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Take a look at the Divs & Spans section of http://watirwebdriver.com/web-elements.  It shows how to retrieve text using the `.text` method, which you can then use for comparison purposes.  Also--to facilitate better answers--you should post the code that you've already tried to solve your problem.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Yes, in future I will post code with all posts wherever possible (seeing as it didn't work I thought it would be stupid... guess not). As a tester - NOT a developer - I am just getting my head wrapped around rubymine + watir. I seem to be getting fairly decent results (really starting to get somewhere with HTML selectors) but I can never seem to follow the tutorials eg. Cucumber & Cheese by Jeff Morgan. Do I really need Cucumber - let alone cheese - to write efficient automation, or would you consider a good knowledge of RM + Watir enough for industry standard automation?

Comment: Take it one step at a time.  I haven't read Cucumber and Cheese (although it's popular and the author maintains the [page-object](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object) gem).  So, learn watir-webdriver.  Then learn rspec so you can use it as a test harness.  Then learn cucumber if you want human-readable specs that map to code.  There is no cheese; I think that's Jeff Morgan's nickname ;)

Comment: OK awesome! Finally knowing the correct order in which to learn things is MEGA useful, thanks. Also, "there is no cheese" sounds like a line from The Matrix :)